# Can I change the rows / composition of a dataset without violating modeling assumptions?

Tags: machine-learning, assumptions, overfitting, feature-engineering

I am building a few models to explain an outcome (let's say customer making a purchase during a visit to a site) from a dataset of ~200k rows with ~66 features (after dummying out categorical variables). For background, the natural purchase rate per visit in the broader dataset is ~20%.

**What I did**

One thing I found that dramatically increases the AUC of my models is to engineer the rows of the dataset a bit. By this, I mean that I:

- Took all the `purchase = 1` instances
- Combined them with an equal number of `purchase = 0` instances, for which I took unique customer IDs in order to make the population as IID as possible

On the training and validation sets, I get a strong AUC, but see a 20% drop in AUC (yes, 20 points) when I move to the test set, which consists of all the site visits from Jan. 2020.

**What I know**

As standard practice, we take a random train-test split of the original dataset. On certain occasions, we might engineer the rows/composition of the dataset:

- Class balancing when there are very few `1`s
- Rotation of images (data augmentation)
- Omitting rows with null values

**My questions**

Is the practice of manipulating the cohort in the way I described leading to violations in assumptions for standard machine learning methods (RF, GBT, penalized LR)?
Is it common to engineer the rows of a dataset when looking at a new problem (instead of just the features)?
Or is this practice fair game, and the drop in AUC coming from terrible overfitting?

Edit to add: Is my method violating the basic assumption that the population the model is developed on and the population to be tested on should be driven by the same data-generating process?

Comment: You're describing undersampling, which is reasonable when there's class imbalance. Other than enforcing unique customer ids are your purchase=0 samples random? And can you just clarify what's in your test set - is it all your data or data you've set aside that the model hasn't seen?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. The `purchase = 0` samples are random, aside from de-duplicating customer IDs. The test set is data the model hasn't seen -- it's been trained on data through 2019 but not at all from 2020.

Comment: You might be seeing [concept drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_drift). I'd check to to see if the distributions of the 2019 and 2020 are similar. KL divergence or maybe mutual information could be useful measures, but even summary statistics on each of the features should give an idea. 2020 has been... different...

Comment: I took a look at summary statistics, and there are some differences. Most of the continuous variables are comparable, but I do notice 3 or 4 that have a [K-S difference] (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) that is 0.1-0.2 rather than being ~0. About half the binary variables appear 10-30% more in the test set than in the dev. set, which makes it harder to accurately stratify cases in the test case. All the categorical variables line up between dev. and test cases.